# C# SQlite - Counting the times a string is repeated using Query (complications)

Tags: c#, .net, database, sqlite

I have a SQLite database that is displayed in a data grid view in my c# windows form. So, this database has four columns. My particular interest is in only one of the columns. The column indicates the type of message. It can be ERRORS or ALARMS or INITIALIZATION etc.. Now I have added functionality where the column can be edited and updated in the database.

Its like , I choose a list of ALARMS and then group them as ALARM # 1 (their type field is updated). Similarly ALARM # 2 and so on...

All this works fine. The problem is when I want to count the number of Alarms. I send a query

```
using(var sda=new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT count(*) from LogDatabase where Type like '%ALARM%'", "data source=" + database_path))
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            int sum_rows_selected=0;
            sda.Fill(dt);
            int alarms_total = Convert.ToInt16(dt.Rows[0][0]);
            MessageBox.Show(alarms_total.ToString());
        }
```

This shows all the fields with ALARM in it.. So, Initially if the DB had 10 rows of Type ALARMS. It shows 10 which is fine. But now when i edit 4 rows as ALARM # 1 and 5 rows as ALARM # 2.. I want the count to be 3 ( #1 as 1, #2 as 1 and rest of ALARMS (1 here) )...

I managed to get some weird logic to get the correct answer but this works only if the ALARMS are edited to #1 or #2 at that time. If i close the window and come back it doesnt work. It shows 10 again...

Help Please

Thanks

Comment: This is a very confusing post.  Can you further explain your last two paragraphs?  I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you're doing here. What does it mean when you say " But now when i edit 4 rows as ALARM # 1 and 5 rows as ALARM # 2"? So now you have 10 rows: 1 with type ALARM, 4 with type ALARM #1 and 5 with type ALARM #2?

Comment: @Tom Hazel I still have 10 rows.. But all the four rows of ALARM # 1 should be counted as 1 ALARM. (not 4)

Comment: @BiggsTRC so, I sometimes group different rows into an Alarm number. I want multiple rows of same Alarm number to be counted as just 1 ALARM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try grouping them:
Not sure if the syntax is different for SQLite, but something like

```
SELECT Type, count(*) from LogDatabase where Type like '%ALARM%' Group by Type
```

This should give you

```
Alarm #1, 4
Alarm #2, 5
Alarm #5, 1
```

My C# is rusty, but to get all the rows for both columns you would need a loop, or a data table, or a lot more variables. Forgive me if I botch up the syntax.

```
string alarms_name[];
int alarms_total[];
int i;
For(i=0;i < dt.Count; i++){
    alarms_name[i] = Convert.ToInt16(dt.Rows[i][0]);
    alarms_total[i] = Convert.ToInt16(dt.Rows[i][1]);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, those would be the row counts for those Types. Fixed it to match your numbers.

Comment: Okay.. I tried the Queries.. Seems to be the right one for me! But I have another small doubt here...  'var dt = new DataTable();''sda.Fill(dt);' ; These two lines will fill the datatable based on the Query right? How can i extract the count value from it... I used to do dt.Rows[0][0] when it was just one value

Comment: As to grouping them by type as a single count... you might be able to do that easily by nesting the select. The difficulty that I see is if you had 4 of #1, 5 of #2, 3 of #3 and 3 of #5, and you only wanted to group #1 and #2; it would be difficult to get it to show Alarm #1 = 1, Alarm #2 = 1, Alarm #3 = 3 and Alarm #5 = 3.

Comment: Yeah, My requirement is to group all as a single count.. ! I think this should work right! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Added a little more for looping through the results. Glad I could help